# Why does Jcreator show iIlegal start of expression?

Tags: java, string, function, jcreator

I am new at programming and currently in our classes we are learning java. I am trying to create a routine in which I need to use `String` variables only. Below it is the code in which I am working with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {

 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in ));
 PrintStream out = System.out;

 String hair.equals("damagedHair");

 cutHair(marvin);
 cleanHair(michelle);

 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

     static void cutHair(String marvin) {
         String cabello;
         marvin.equals(hair);
         if (marvin.equals("damagedHair")) {
             cabello.equals("newHaircut");
             result(hair);

         }


         static void cleanHair(String michelle) {
             String hair;
             michelle.equals(hair);
             if (michelle.equals(newHaircut)) {
                 hair.equals("putShampooAndConditioner");
                 result(hair);


             }
             static void result(String pHair) {;

                 PrintStream out = System.out;

                 out.println("=============");
                 out.println(pHair);
                 out.println("=============");
             }


         }
```

Jcreator is giving me an error that says `Illegal start of expression` and also `java 50 error ';' expected`.

I am not sure why is this coming up and I am a little confused as to whether I am doing something I am not supposed to and how to correct it. Sorry about the double posting, this is the right message. Need some help from you guys to figure this out.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: You can't define methods in a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in your main:

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    static void cutHair(String marvin)
    {
        String cabello;
        marvin.equals(hair); 

       if(marvin.equals("damagedHair"))
       {
        cabello.equals("newHaircut");
        result(hair);
       }   
    }
```

You cannot define methods inside of main.  Also, `hair` is not in scope here, ie it's in your main, not your method.  Additionally, you're constantly only declaring variables, and then using them without them ever having been initialized. For example, in the above method, you have:

```
cabello.equals("newHairCut")
```

but `cabello` was never initialized, this should give you a `might not have been initialized warning`.  Or earlier in your code, you have:

```
 String hair.equals("damagedHair");
```

Again, this doesn't make any sense.  You just declared `hair` here, you cannot call methods on it until you initialize it.  I suggest that you review some tutorials.

Comment: No problem.  If you feel that I adequately answered your question, please accept my answer.  Also, you should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).